# Why is Task.WaitAll not waiting until all of my Tasks have completed? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Before I start. I have looked at similar questions and I don't think they have an answer in my situation.

I am having problems with Task.Factory.StartNew and Task.WaitAll.

I am getting null exceptions on a object within a created class that is initialized in the task, even though the code that is throwing a null exception should be waiting until all tasks are complete.

If I run this code without the tasks it works fine.

Why is Task.WaitAll not waiting until all of the Tasks have been completed?

```
        Queue<Task> tasks = new Queue<Task>();
        //Go through all transactions in the file via the reader.
        foreach (transaction t in xr.read_x12(_progressbar_all_processing)) {
            tasks.Enqueue(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                //Create a new provider from the current transaction and then
                //add it to the global provider list.
                provider p = new provider(t);

                t_info.provider_list.Add(p);

                //Null out the segments of the current transaction
                //We are done with them and now the garbage collector
                //can clean them up for us.
                t.segments = null;
            }));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        foreach(provider p in t_info.providers){
              //Every provider has a List<claims> claims_list
              //Do something with p.claims_list
              foreach(claim c in p.claims_list){ //<--null exception here

              }
        }
```

Comment: You should never use `StartNew` [without providing a task scheduler](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (this is not your problem, but somthing you should be aware of). For your actual problem, what is the type of `t_info.provider_list`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Thanks I will keep that in mind.

Comment: It is List<provider> and provider has a List<claim> All of this is generated in the provider constructor

Comment: @Quantic if the task was faulted `Task.WaitAll` will throw a `AggragateException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t_info.provider_list` is a `List<provider>` this class is not safe to have multiple threads write to it at once, you must synchronize access to the list.

```
lock(t_info.provider_list)
{
    t_info.provider_list.Add(p);
}
```

This will only allow a single thread to do the Add call at a time and will fix your issues with a broken collection.

Comment: Thanks Scott, This seems to have solved my issue. I will try to be more careful with my threads in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion to make this easier to get right: use `Task.WhenAll` instead. Make each of your tasks return a value which is the result of its own unit of work.

`WhenAll` has the signature:

```
Task<TResult[]> WhenAll<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks)
```

[Task.WhenAll on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx)

So you pass it a collection of tasks that each evaluate to a `TResult` and you get back a task that evaluates to an array containing all the results when they're done.

This way, you are absolved of any responsibility for using thread-safe collections to pass data between tasks. It's much harder to get wrong.

It's also compatible with `async`/`await`, which is all about consuming values returned via tasks.